# How to setup a Bridge connection for enp0s3 CentOS7 on Oracle VirtualBox

Tags: networking, bridge, centos-7, static-ip

I'm running a **CentOS Linux release 7.2.1511 (Core)** 64-bit on an Oracle VM VirtualBox and I wanted my local machine (Windows) to be able to connect to my VM because I want to use it for local hosting for testing. To my understanding, to be able to achieve this I have to use **Bridged Adapter**. I checked several sites on how to configure my network and found this configuration for **enp0s3**:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/278637/centos-minimal-installation-static-ip-address

```
DEVICE=enp0s3
HWADDR=your_mac_addr
TYPE=Ethernet
UUID=your_UUID
ONBOOT=yes
NM_CONTROLLED=no
BOOTPROTO=none
IPADDR=192.168.0.35
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
GATEWAY=192.168.0.1
DNS1=8.8.8.8
IPV6INIT=no
USERCTL=no
```

The problem is, when I tried to follow this and set my adapter to Bridged in Oracle VirtualBox my Machine suddenly cannot connect to the internet. 
Originally my VM can connect to internet as well as ping my local machine, just not the other way around.

On windows:

- IP: **10.120.20.71**
- Subnet Mask: **255.255.255.0**
- Default Gateway :
  **10.120.20.1**

On CentOS7:

```
TYPE="Ethernet"
BOOTPROTO=none
NM_CONTROLLED=no
USERCTL=no
IPADDR=10.0.2.15
GATEWAY=10.120.20.1
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
DNS1=8.8.8.8
DEFROUTE="yes"
PEERDNS="yes"
PEERROUTES="yes"
IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL="no"
IPV6INIT="yes"
IPV6_AUTOCONF="yes"
IPV6_DEFROUTE="yes"
IPV6_FAILURE_FATAL="no"
NAME="enp0s3"
UUID=<UUID>
DEVICE="enp0s3"
ONBOOT="yes"
```

I also found this https://gist.github.com/fernandoaleman/2172388 and tried configuring **ifcfg-enp0s3**, **/etc/sysconfig/network** and **/etc/resolv.conf** and the same thing happens.

Comment: What is your host's ip address?

Comment: If you're setting it to bridged it has to be on the same network as the host. So change the guest ip address to something like 10.120.20.35 and the gateway 10.120.20.1. The example answer you linked to assumes the host is on the 192.168.0.0/24 network.

Comment: Hi , does it matter if I configure /etc/sysconfig/network and /etc/resolv.conf?

Comment: You last edit still has them on separate networks

Comment: wow! thanks lol! omg. I feel so dumb lol.  [n8te](https://superuser.com/users/627136/n8te) you  were right XD I should have used 10.120.20.XX something for it. It's working now

Comment: Glad you got it going

Answer (score 3):

The steps provided in the link (that you attached) [gist](https://gist.github.com/fernandoaleman/2172388) work fine.
Probably you forgot to change the line : "BOOTPROTO=none" to "BOOTPROTO=static". Also the gateway should be defined in /etc/sysconfig/network rather than ifcfg-enp0s3.
Below the steps described in the link with some modifications:

## Configure enp0s3

## `#vi /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-enp0s3`

```bsh
DEVICE=enp0s3
NM_CONTROLLED=yes
ONBOOT=yes
HWADDR=<Your MAC @>
TYPE=Ethernet
BOOTPROTO=static
NAME=enp0s3
UUID=5fb06bd0-0bb0-7ffb-45f1-d6edd65f3e03
IPADDR=192.168.1.44
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
```

## Configure Default Gateway

## `#vi /etc/sysconfig/network`

```bash
NETWORKING=yes
HOSTNAME=centos6
GATEWAY=192.168.1.1
```

## Configure DNS Server

## `#vi /etc/resolv.conf`

```bsh
nameserver 8.8.8.8      # Replace with your nameserver ip
nameserver 192.168.1.1 # Replace with your nameserver ipenter code here
```

#### restart NetworkManager and network

```bash
$systemctl restart NetworkManager  
$systemctl restart network
```

PS : ahh didn't seen the above comments, any way just to mention all the steps as advised by [music2myear](https://superuser.com/users/74026/music2myear)
 in the comment below.

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser. Please use the EDIT button and add the relevant information from the link you've provided in the body of this answer. Leave the link itself only for attribution and further research. It should not be necessary to actually visit the link to get the answer. Right now this is what we call a "link only answer". If the link changes or goes dead your answer is no longer helpful.

Comment: Yes i agreed, it's a waste of time to switch from a website to another for an answer, thanks for your advice.

Comment: It's more an issue of if the link goes bad, so does your answer. We want SuperUser answers to remain relevant, and if they go bad we end up with questions without answers, making for a lot of useless posts when someone a few years later comes up with the same problem. Thanks for adding the information. This is a very good answer.